How to publish to icecast directory listings
I'm running Icecast 2.4.4 on Windows 10, 10GB of DDR3 RAM,  I'm using the Winamp player and the Edcast 3 stand alone installed, my public URL is:http://192.168.100.60:8000/ streaming OGG Vorbis format @ 96kbps
http://192.168.100.60:8000/status.xsl
I've followed the instructions from the Icecast 2.4.1 Docs — YP Directories and here is portion of the code for my config file below
  </authentication>

    <!-- set the mountpoint for a shoutcast source to use, the default if not
         specified is /stream but you can change it here if an alternative is
         wanted or an extension is required
    <shoutcast-mount>/live.nsv</shoutcast-mount>
    -->

    
<directory>
    <yp-url-timeout>15</yp-url-timeout>
    <yp-url>http://dir.xiph.org/cgi-bin/yp-cgi</yp-url>
</directory>

    <!-- You may have multiple <listener> elements -->
    <listen-socket>
        <port>8000</port>
        <!-- <bind-address>127.0.0.1</bind-address> -->
        <!-- <shoutcast-mount>/stream</shoutcast-mount> -->
    </listen-socket>
    <!--
    <listen-socket>
        <port>8080</port>
    </listen-socket>
    -->
    <!--
    <listen-socket>
        <port>8443</port>
        <ssl>1</ssl>
    </listen-socket>
    -->

Now when I go to the directory and search for my station name I don't get any result. I've done all of that and yet my station isn't featured on the directory. What Am I doing wrong? Please provide the correct steps
I have removed the comment for the directory section
<directory>
    <yp-url-timeout>15</yp-url-timeout>
    <yp-url>http://dir.xiph.org/cgi-bin/yp-cgi</yp-url>
</directory>

and I even had all the station details there at one point meaning stream name, description, bitrate and location but I removed all that because it was not in the instructions. I've also restarted the server after every change, yet the issue still remains.

192.168.100.60 is in the RFC1918 private network space 192.168.0.0/16. This is a local address that's only reachable on your local network.
You'll want to learn about port forwarding and to check if your router/gateway has a public IP address or is behind CGNAT. It's complex.
